# Maui Android Binding Class For Brother Mobile Printing SDK

Tags: printing, xamarin.android, maui, .net-7.0, brother-print-sdk

Jumped on the maui development train with a new mobile android app.  Intent is this app will print out a docket on a Brother RJ2050 mobile printer.

I've downloaded the SDK and followed the instructions from here (Adding an Android Java Library Binding project rather than the Xamarin version). https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/guide/getting-started/getting-started-cross-platform.html#bind-the-sdk-for-android

All good so far, problem is when I try building this, I get a heap of CS0535 Errors, For example *'MWPrintSettings' does not implement interface member 'IPrintImageSettings.GetHalfTone()'* and a number of warnings of different nature.

As an experiment, created a Xamarin Android Bindings Library followed the instructions and compiled fine.  Of course can't include that in my Maui app though.

Wondering if anyone might have some thoughts?  Or is it just plain the Brother Mobile SDK isn't going to work in this environment (Being .net7 maui)?

Comment: I don't see any update (for .Net 7) of the Xamarin Android BIndings Library doc. [Maui Issue: Native Bindings](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/248) says its up to the ".Net Android/iOS" teams to solve this. You could add a new issue at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android. See if you get a response there.

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve.  After some more playing think it's just the Brother SDK is out of date.  Didn't seem to like .Net Standard 2.0 either.

Comment: Hi, what solution did you come up with? I have downloaded the latest version 4.6.4 and I'm also getting this issue building a Android Java Library, if I use an older version of the Brother SDK that I have in my Xamarin binding project it compiles without issues but could do with getting the newer version working as it supports newer printers.

Comment: Didn’t use it in the end,  just zpl commands